# If i click from 3 to 1 tab the selected radio button answer class is removed .but working fine for immediate neighbours?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

The below function works on Next button click

```
function show_tab(id) {[enter image description here][1]

    showStuff(id);  
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";

    $('a button.tab-selected').removeClass('tab-selected');
    $("#c2").addClass("tab-selected");

}
```

here is rendered html

```
                <div>
                    <div class="cerca-tab-group flex-container-stretch" id="tab-group">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1"><button class="cerca-tab tab-selected border-left " id="c1" type="button" onclick="showStuff('tab-1')">1</button></a>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2"><button class="cerca-tab " type="button" name="2" value="2" id="c2" onclick="showStuff('tab-2')">2</button></a>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-3"><button class="cerca-tab " type="button" name="3" value="3" id="c3" onclick="showStuff('tab-3')">3</button></a>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-4"><button class="cerca-tab " type="button" name="4" value="4" id="c4" onclick="showStuff('tab-4')">4</button></a>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-5"><button class="cerca-tab border-right " type="button" name="5" id="c5" onclick="showStuff('tab-5')">5</button></a>
```

here is the rendered html

#### 1. Race is determined solely by biology:

Not Quite!
                                                    
                                                    
                                                        Oops! That is not the correct answer.
                                                    
                                                
                                            
                                        
                                                True
                                                
False

                                        
                                    



                        
                            Check Answer
                            Next

Comment: Show us the rendered html.

Comment: Is it not the renderd html what i have posted?

Comment: Please tell what you mean

Comment: rendered html wont have `foreach` and `if` conditions